# NTFRS event ID13508

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain, replication

So every day for the past xx months, our server(DC1) are reporting a NTFRS error #13508.

Its giving an error about having trouble replicating with DC2, which is the other domain controller at that site.

It says it has problems with the DNS name of the DC2, which I find weird because they are both DNS server with each other as their primary and themselves as the secondary.

Is this a DNS issue or a DC1 issue, DC1 is running 2008R2 while all the other domain controllers are running 2012 or 2012R2.

What would you recommend I try first

EDIT:
i can verify FRS is running on both, and the DNS entries for both servers are fine.

I am also suspicious of our DNS because I plugged in a computer earlier and it took over 2 hours for the DNS entry to replicate from DC3 to DC2

EDIT 2:

the error:

```
    The File Replication Service is having trouble enabling replication from DC2 to DC1 for c:\windows\sysvol\domain using the DNS name DC2.mydomain.com. FRS will keep retrying. 
 Following are some of the reasons you would see this warning. 

 [1] FRS can not correctly resolve the DNS name DC2.mydomain.com from this computer. 
 [2] FRS is not running on DC2.mydomain.com. 
 [3] The topology information in the Active Directory Domain Services for this replica has not yet replicated to all the Domain Controllers. 

 This event log message will appear once per connection, After the problem is fixed you will see another event log message indicating that the connection has been established.
```

Comment: Why are you still using FRS? It is obsolete, notoriously unreliable, and much more difficult to troubleshoot than DFSR. Not much love around here for obsolete technologies when there has been a far superior free built in alternative for eight years.

Comment: I havent heard of DFSR, is it available on 2008? And is FRS the cause of our DNS issues?

Comment: `It says it has problems with the DNS name of the DC2, which I find weird because they are both DNS server with each other as their primary and themselves as the secondary` - I'm not understanding how you think that's a validation that DNS is actually working correctly? `is FRS the cause of our DNS issues?` - No. FRS can't cause DNS problems, but DNS could cause FRS problems. Additionally, DNS isn't the only possible cause of FRS issues. What have you done to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Do you also have event ID 13509s in the event log, after the 13508s?

Comment: I dont have the 13509. the 13508 appears to be happening frequently. I have tried troubleshooting dns but after looking on DNS technets and such, I assume DNS is in best practice. Pings between the domain controllers dont drop packets so I am kinda lost. I am new to the industry which doesnt help

Comment: Hi Cteneyck Your question can you paste the event viewer logs from File replication service, your question cannot be understood.

Comment: i have included the exact error for the ntfrs. I think you may be right that its a DNS issue but why can I ping a hostname but frs cant?

Comment: Migrating from FRS to DFS is pretty painless, I'd recommend it.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2014/06/25/streamlined-migration-of-frs-to-dfsr-sysvol/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by switch from FRS to DFS